# Splitting a URL path against RFC

Tags: php, url, rfc2396

Is there a specific (standardised) way of splitting up a URL path in to path components? I’ve looked at RFC 2396 and can’t see a routine for doing so.

Originally I just used PHP’s `explode()` method to break the string into an array when it encounters each `/`, but when testing it against Cocoa's `NSURL` class, I get two different results:

The test URL: https://example.com/rest/api///v2.1.1/noun/verb////12345/additional/stuff///

NSURL:

```
["/", "rest", "api", "v2.1.1", "noun", "verb", "12345", "additional", "stuff", "/“]
```

My PHP method:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => rest [2] => api [3] => [4] => [5] => v2.1.1 [6] => noun [7] => verb [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => 12345 [12] => additional [13] => stuff [14] => [15] => [16] => )
```

I realise RFC 2396 has been replaced with RFC 3986, but NSURL uses 2396 and that’s what I’m testing against as it’ll be the client side implementation.

Comment: In particular, I should note that I’m looking for a way to find out how to reserve specific information (such as a leading and trailing slash) and how to determine what data shouldn’t be kept - without making a guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard way to do this and to be honest, I'm not that familiar with RFC2396.

However, for your given example, you could use `preg_split('#\/+#', $uriPath)` to split by any number of forward slashes and then check if the first and last elements of the resulting array are empty strings - if they are, replace them by a single slash each.

Comment: This is a similar solution I went for in the end too. Thanks though :)